# Commit using a different account in your github repository

Tags: git, github

I have 2 GitHub accounts - Account A and B and i am working on repository xyz under my account A.If i need to make a commit using Account B in my Account A repository what prerequisite information should i have about Account B with me to make a commit . Is Account B user name and email id linked to git hub suffice to make a commit for Account A by using .

```
  $git config user.name accountB
  $git config user.email accountB@gmail.com
```

Do i need Account B password or ssh key to make a commit to Account A or account name and account email id is suffice

Comment: For Git, there is no connection between the user&email used to make a commit and the Github account. They can be configured completely independently.

Comment: but in the commit history i want account B to show up his commit rather than account A

Answer (score 0):

To create a commit with a different name and email address, you must change your configuration of `user.name` and `user.email`. To change them permanently, use

```
git config user.name accountB
git config user.email accountB@gmail.com
```

and make commits. To change these settings for only one commit, you can use

```
git -c user.name="accountB" -c user.email=accountB@gmail.com commit
```

Note that these settings have nothing to do with your Github account. They are not even security related. They do not change whether you can push to Github or not or which Github account you push to.